# Smoothly close an SVG path with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg, smoothing, bezier

I'm working on some code where a user drops a number or points/markers and a Bezier curved SVG line is drawn through them (so a smooth line connects all the points). It's based off

https://codepen.io/francoisromain/pen/dzoZZj

`svg.innerHTML = svgPath(points, bezierCommand)`

An example path that I've created is:

```html
<svg width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="100 200 500 400">
  <path d="M 346,186.5 C 374,208.875 452,237.875 458,276 C 464,314.125 433.75,340.5 370,339 C 306.25,337.5 253,307.75 203,270 C 153,232.25 134.75,209 170,188 C 205.25,167 300.5,186.5 344,186">
</svg>
```

So far it's working well till I get to closing the line. If I add Z it abruptly joins the points.

The closing needs to be (if necessary) a curve so that there's a gentle transition from the last point to the first and on to the second... i.e. the whole path becomes a "smooth" loop.

I tried adding a Bezier curve but the join ends up being a sharp bump. And I tried adding another point close to the first and then using Z but again I get a sharp bump.

How can this be done?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+close+svg+path+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: But on a JS code note, don't set `innerHTML` on the top-level SVG. Find the path element and set its `d` attribute to the path it needs to show. If you need a closed curve, rather than a line, you'll have to create you own "final Q or C curve that ends at the same coordinate as your starting coordinate, and _then_ your Z.

Comment: I have search SO for answers but I couldn't find anything I could use. The one post from 10 years ago that offered an answer linked to a page that no longer exists. I did search with Google but the few answers I found were in coding languages I couldn't interpret.

I can close the curve by adding an additional C curve but the issue remains that it doesn't smoothly connect to the start point - I get an abrupt change.
I'm trying to create a closed Bezier curve that runs through a set of points but without the closing curve creating a abrupt change (angled bump) where it meets the start point.

Comment: I think I've found a solution. I highly recommend changing the post title to something like "Smooth a closed Svg path with cubic bezier curves" - it's currently a bit ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the original function to return a pathData (according to the SVG 2 [SVGPathData interface draft](https://svgwg.org/specs/paths/#InterfaceSVGPathData)) the  array instead of a `d` attribute string.
This way, we can easily manipulate and sort commands.

I've also changed the coordinate structure so we're working with **point objects**.

```
[
  { x: 344, y: 186 }
]
```

instead of

```
[
  [ 344, 186 ]
]
```

This pretty handy, since most native methods like `getPointAtLength()` or properties like `points` also return coordinates as objects

### Extend the polyline by appending the first 2 point to the point array

```
     points = [
      { x: 344, y: 186 },
      { x: 458, y: 276 },
      { x: 370, y: 339 },
      { x: 203, y: 270 },
      { x: 170, y: 188 },
       //duplicated points from the beginning
      { x: 344, y: 186 },
      { x: 458, y: 276 },
       
    ];
```

```
  // append first 2 points for closed paths
  if (closed) {
    points = points.concat(points.slice(0, 2));
  }
```

This way the function will create a smooth curve between first/last and second vertice.

[image: polyline smoothed]

Obviously, this path has an overlapping curve segment, we need to remove. Besides, the first `C` and needs some adjustment.

### Copy last `C` commands 1. control point and delete last command

We can copy the last command's 1st control point to the first `C` command.

```
  // copy last commands 1st controlpoint to first curveto
  if (closed) {
    let comLast = pathData[pathData.length - 1];
    let valuesLastC = comLast.values;
    let valuesFirstC = pathData[1].values;
    
    pathData[1] = {
      type: "C",
      values: [valuesLastC[0], valuesLastC[1], valuesFirstC.slice(2)].flat()
    };
    // delete last curveto
    pathData = pathData.slice(0, pathData.length - 1); 
  }
```

```js
let points = [
  { x: 344, y: 186 },
  { x: 458, y: 276 },
  { x: 370, y: 339 },
  { x: 203, y: 270 },
  { x: 170, y: 188 }
];


let smoothing = 0.3;
let pathData = getCurvePathData(points, smoothing, true);

// serialize pathData to d attribute string
let d = pathDataToD(pathData, 1);
path.setAttribute("d", d);


// Render the svg <path> element
function getCurvePathData(points, smoothing = 0.2, closed=true){ 
  
  // append first 2 points for closed paths
  if (closed) {
    points = points.concat(points.slice(0, 2));
  }
  
  // Properties of a line
  const line = (pointA, pointB) => {
    const lengthX = pointB.x - pointA.x;
    const lengthY = pointB.y - pointA.y;
    return {
      length: Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lengthX, 2) + Math.pow(lengthY, 2)),
      angle: Math.atan2(lengthY, lengthX)
    };
  };

  // Position of a control point
  const controlPoint = (current, previous, next, reverse) => {
    const p = previous || current;
    const n = next || current;
    const o = line(p, n);

    const angle = o.angle + (reverse ? Math.PI : 0);
    const length = o.length * smoothing;

    const x = current.x + Math.cos(angle) * length;
    const y = current.y + Math.sin(angle) * length;
    return { x, y };
  };

  let pathData = [];
  pathData.push({ type: "M", values: [points[0].x, points[0].y] });

  for (let i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    let point = points[i];
    const cp1 = controlPoint(points[i - 1], points[i - 2], point);
    const cp2 = controlPoint(point, points[i - 1], points[i + 1], true);
    //console.log( i, 'a', a)
    const command = {
      type: "C",
      values: [cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, point.x, point.y]
    };

    pathData.push(command);
  }
  
  // copy last commands 1st controlpoint to first curveto
  if (closed) {
    let comLast = pathData[pathData.length - 1];
    let valuesLastC = comLast.values;
    let valuesFirstC = pathData[1].values;
    
    pathData[1] = {
      type: "C",
      values: [valuesLastC[0], valuesLastC[1], valuesFirstC.slice(2)].flat()
    };
    // delete last curveto
    pathData = pathData.slice(0, pathData.length - 1); 
  }
  
  return pathData;
};

// convert pathdata to d attribute string
function pathDataToD(pathData, decimals=3){
  let d = pathData
  .map((com) => {
    return `${com.type}${com.values.map(value=>{return +value.toFixed(decimals)}).join(" ")}`;
  })
  .join(" ");
  return d;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg">
  <path id="pathPoly" fill="none" stroke="green"></path>
  <path id="path" fill="none" stroke="#000"></path>
</svg>
```

See original post by François Romain: [Smooth a Svg path with cubic bezier curves](https://francoisromain.medium.com/smooth-a-svg-path-with-cubic-bezier-curves-e37b49d46c74))

Comment: Thanks I think I've got it working nicely. One other question thought. Is the reason for the polygon in the SVG as something to use as a store for the points' coords? That is, if I could get/set the coords from, say, a db then I could dispense with the polygon?

Comment: Pardon me, the polygon element was just intended to illustrate the benefits of using point obects like `{x:10, y:50}` instead of `[10, 50]`. Adding a `<polygon>` with coordinates e.g. retrieved from a data base can be handy to get a first visualization of your data and calculating an appropriate `viewBox`. So no, you don't need a polygon - I'll remove it from the eaxmple. But please consider to revise the post title as suggested (especially the term "loop" is usually used for programming loops).